# How to use web service with Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) enable in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, csrf, csrf-protection

i have web and mobile application . mobile application use web service that are build in php codeigniter with Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) enabled.

So my question is how to access web service ? it always return a message

```
<h1>An Error Was Encountered</h1>
<p>The action you have requested is not allowed.</p>
```

Comment: hows you request to the web services? with ajax, curl or something else?

Comment: using curl or something else.... not ajax

Answer (score 0):

Have your requesting page include at least one form input, which is usually hidden. This will ensure that codeigniter will send a token with the request.

see this Question and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11269439/32763).

Comment: yes that's right . but my question is how to use it within web service that call from mobile application .

Comment: How are you calling the service? If you're using something like ajax, you can include the token in your call. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10897074/32763