# CODEIGNITER ajax fail

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i have this ajax code (with codeigniter framework)

```
function api_voiture_update(func_success, data, voiture_id,  num, nom, prenom, entite, direction, immatriculation, marque, modele, finition, segment, boite, loueur, forfaitkm, duree, datedebut, datefin, ct, alerte, emissionsco2, etiquetteco2, consokm, couleur,gps , puissancech, cvfiscaux, energie, categorie, classe, telepeage, cartec, cartetotal, km, date, email_c, dateaffec, telephone, tco, tcoreel, tvs, pneuete, pneuhiver, loyermen, maintenance, pneu, loyerttc, amortissement, prixttc, prixoption, prixremise, optionre, remise, bonus, prixtotal, prixenergie, assurance, renonciation, avtnature, daterea, nomrea, comrea, couttotal, carbuanuel, comsuivi, comoption, alertect, checkct, checktotal, checktele) {

var options = {token: user.token, voiture_id: voiture_id, num: num, nom: nom, prenom: prenom, entite: entite, direction: direction, immatriculation: immatriculation, marque: marque, modele: modele, finition: finition, segment: segment, boite: boite, loueur: loueur, forfaitkm: forfaitkm, duree: duree, datedebut: datedebut, datefin: datefin, ct: ct, alerte: alerte, emissionsco2: emissionsco2, etiquetteco2: etiquetteco2, consokm, couleur: couleur, gps: gps, puissancech: puissancech, cvfiscaux: cvfiscaux, energie: energie, categorie: categorie, classe: classe, telepeage: telepeage, cartec: cartec, cartetotal: cartetotal, km: km, date: date, email_c: email_c, dateaffec: dateaffec, telephone: telephone, tco: tco, tcoreel: tcoreel, tvs: tvs, pneuete: pneuete, pneuhiver: pneuhiver, loyermen: loyermen, maintenance: maintenance, pneu: pneu, loyerttc: loyerttc, amortissement: amortissement, prixttc: prixttc, prixoption: prixoption, prixremise: prixremise, optionre: optionre, remise: remise, bonus: bonus, prixtotal: prixtotal, prixenergie: prixenergie, assurance: assurance, renonciation: renonciation, avtnature: avtnature, daterea: daterea, nomrea: nomrea, comrea: comrea, couttotal: couttotal, carbuanuel: carbuanuel, comsuivi: comsuivi, comoption: comoption, alertect: alertect, checkct: checkct, checktotal: checktotal, checktele: checktotal, ids: user.ids, statu: user.statu};
var data2 = $.extend({}, data, options);
alert(JSON.stringify(data2));
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: base_url + 'voiture/update',
    data: data2,
    error: function(data) {
        error = $.parseJSON(data.responseText).error;
        func_error(error);
    },
    success: function(data)
    {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        if (data.length === 0)
            alert("Les modifications n'ont pas été prises en compte, veuillez recommencer.");
        console.log(data);
        func_success(data);
    }
});
}
```

data of the extend is a getFormData of my form.
The problem is that, with the alert of data2, array isn't empty, but with the alert of data, it is empty.
But data = data2, so i don't understand.

And, in more, this bug doesn't come all the time, one time it work, data isn't empty, and the other time, it fail.

Thanks for your read.

Comment: Are you passing csrf token
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269439/how-to-include-csrf-from-codeigniter-into-ajax-data

Answer (score 0):

`base_url()` is server side code so wont work in front end.
Use

```
  var getUrl = window.location;
  var baseUrl = getUrl .protocol + "//" + getUrl.host + "/" + getUrl.pathname.split('/')[1];
```

to get the base url in frontend

Comment: if your script is in a js file five a full path  else if it is in the view page  you can `<?= base_url() ?>`

Comment: base_url is just a variable : base_url = '/index2.php/'; It isn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

pass data like

data : {token: user.token, voiture_id: voiture_id, num: num, nom: nom, prenom: prenom, entite: entite, direction: direction, immatriculation: immatriculation, marque: marque, modele: modele, finition: finition, segment: segment, boite: boite, loueur: loueur, forfaitkm: forfaitkm, duree: duree, datedebut: datedebut, datefin: datefin, ct: ct, alerte: alerte, emissionsco2: emissionsco2, etiquetteco2: etiquetteco2, consokm, couleur: couleur, gps: gps, puissancech: puissancech, cvfiscaux: cvfiscaux, energie: energie, categorie: categorie, classe: classe, telepeage: telepeage, cartec: cartec, cartetotal: cartetotal, km: km, date: date, email_c: email_c, dateaffec: dateaffec, telephone: telephone, tco: tco, tcoreel: tcoreel, tvs: tvs, pneuete: pneuete, pneuhiver: pneuhiver, loyermen: loyermen, maintenance: maintenance, pneu: pneu, loyerttc: loyerttc, amortissement: amortissement, prixttc: prixttc, prixoption: prixoption, prixremise: prixremise, optionre: optionre, remise: remise, bonus: bonus, prixtotal: prixtotal, prixenergie: prixenergie, assurance: assurance, renonciation: renonciation, avtnature: avtnature, daterea: daterea, nomrea: nomrea, comrea: comrea, couttotal: couttotal, carbuanuel: carbuanuel, comsuivi: comsuivi, comoption: comoption, alertect: alertect, checkct: checkct, checktotal: checktotal, checktele: checktotal, ids: user.ids, statu: user.statu}

Comment: i can't do that because otherwise all the value will be null. the value of array come from the extend.

Comment: are u need to post json data

Comment: if yes add  dataType: "json"

Comment: it doesn't work, i just try, and it fail at the secondy try